# SQL: Append result set of first result to back of second result?

Tags: sql, t-sql

first time actually posting here. Have learned alot from reading posts though! My problem: Trying to make a random Canadian SIN generator to automate some customer test account inserts. I don't want to do this by function, want it to all be in one query I can execute to call it for a insert later.

I am trying to append the CheckDigit to the back of the SIN. So @SIN + CheckDigit result. Any help is much appreciated!

Current example result I get is
CheckDigit
2
SIN
28111173

```
DECLARE @SIN int
SET @SIN= (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(81091888-13323110)+13323110))

DECLARE @IMEI int = @SIN; -- Check digit(last digit)

WITH SINVerify (n) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (LEN(@IMEI))
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
)
--Luhn algorithm
(SELECT CheckDigit=9*SUM(SumOfDigits)%10
FROM SINVerify a
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT [Digit*Multiplier] = (1+n%2) * SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@IMEI), n, 1)
) b
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT SumOfDigits = [Digit*Multiplier]%10 + [Digit*Multiplier]/10
) c)

(SELECT @SIN AS 'SIN')
```

Comment: I suspect your query is probably overkill for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select cast(@sin as char(10)) + cast(@checkdigit as char(1)) as SIN
```

Comment: That was it! Guess I was overthinking this.. Just needed to declare @CheckDigit and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you could condense that quite a bit and remove some unnecessary complexities in there:

```
-- testing
select sin, (n % 2 + 1) as weight, sin / cast(power(10, n) as int) % 10 as digit
from
    (select cast(floor(rand()*(81091888-13323110)+13323110) as int)) s(sin)
    cross apply
    (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) a(n);

-- final output
select sum((n % 2 + 1) * (sin / cast(power(10, n) as int) % 10)) % 10 as checkdigit
from
    (select cast(floor(rand()*(81091888-13323110)+13323110) as int)) s(sin)
    cross apply
    (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) a(n);
```